# How to use an Electron <webview> tag in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, jsx

At the top of my module, I have

```
declare module 'react' {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      webview: Electron.WebviewTag
    }
  }
}
```

then in my render method I have

```
  render() {
    const {classes: c} = this.props

    return (
      <webview
        className={c.webview}
        ref={this.webviewRef}
        src={getFileUrl('annotator/StandaloneEntry.html')}
        nodeintegration="true"
        webpreferences="nodeIntegrationInWorker"
        nodeintegrationinsubframes="true"
        disablewebsecurity="true"
        allowpopups="true"
      />
    )
  }
```

but TypeScript complains that `Property 'addEventListener' is missing`:

[image]

[image]

Plus, by writing that `declare module` override in my code, it make all other intrinsic element typings break in all my other files. For example:

[image]

Also also tried to change my JSX declaration as

```
declare namespace JSX {
  export interface IntrinsicElements {
    webview: Electron.WebviewTag
  }
}
```

or

```
declare namespace JSX {
  interface IntrinsicElements {
    webview: Electron.WebviewTag
  }
}
```

but those don't work.

If I give up on JSX for this one, and manually use `React.createElement` instead, then it just works:

```
    return React.createElement('webview', {
      ref: this.webviewRef,
      className: c.webview,
      src: getFileUrl('annotator/StandaloneEntry.html'),
      nodeintegration: 'true',
      nodeintegrationinsubframes: 'true',
      webpreferences: 'nodeIntegrationInWorker',
      disablewebsecurity: 'true', // does 'false' stille work?
      allowpopups: 'true',
    })
```

Any ideas how to make `webview` work properly with JSX in TypeScript, while also not breaking all other intrinsic element types?

Similar question here: [Control a WebView object in Electron with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048143/control-a-webview-object-in-electron-with-typescript)

EDIT: I also tried `declare module JSX`, but no luck:

First it tells me that `JSX` is "declared but its value is never read":

[image]

[image]

And I get an error with the `<webview>` regarding `HTMLWebViewElement`, so the `<webview>` is not being treated as an `Electron.WebviewTag` element:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An ambient module definition for JSX should do the trick:

```
import { WebviewTag } from 'electron';

declare module JSX {
 interface IntrinsicElements {
   webview: WebviewTag;
 }
}
```

See a relevant Github issue [TSX rejects custom elements](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4648#issuecomment-137845601)
and the docs for [ambient modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules)

Comment: Hi jaws, I gave that a try, but no luck. I added screenshots of that showing the new errors that I get.

Comment: I think the `WebviewTag` type definition is incorrectly requiring its function properties. Have you tried using `Partial<Electron.WebviewTag>` with your initial approach?

Answer (score 0):

To augment module (vs declare module) add `import 'moduleName'` before:

```
import 'react';
declare module 'react' {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      webview: Electron.WebviewTag
    }
  }
}
```